# disparity map using CUDA StereoBM looks dark

Tags: image, opencv

I'm working on creating disparity map using **cv::cuda::stereoBM**. Comaring with CPU version, the map looks much darker and I'm not sure if it makes sense. As shown in the following result I got, the left person in the **CUDA** disparity map is almost lost, and I cannot do the further distance calculation.

For now, I found the data type of disparity map using **CUDA is CV_8U**, whereas CPU version is in **CV_16S**(need converting when using imshow). I didn't adjust the argument of data type though, don't know why they are different. I guess this might be the critical reason but got no idea how to improve the map.

Here is the example I followed( its using CPU tho): Basically just create a left disparity map, a right disparity map, and then use both of them and do a post-filtering. (I got a different result using **CUDA** not only on the final filtered result but also the right map).

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html

my result using CPU
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv0TK.jpg)

my result using GPU
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzJ15.jpg)

```
    Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> left_matcher = cuda::createStereoBM(96, 15);
    left_matcher->compute(GPUrgb1, GPUrgb2, d_left_disp);

    int min_disp = left_matcher->getMinDisparity();
    int num_disp = left_matcher->getNumDisparities();
    int wsize = left_matcher->getBlockSize();
    Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> right_matcher = cuda::createStereoBM(num_disp, wsize);
    Ptr<DisparityWLSFilter> wls_filter;
    wls_filter = createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher);
    right_matcher->setMinDisparity(-(min_disp + num_disp) + 1);
    right_matcher->setTextureThreshold(0);
    right_matcher->setUniquenessRatio(0);
    right_matcher->setDisp12MaxDiff(1000000);
    right_matcher->setSpeckleWindowSize(0);
    right_matcher->compute(GPUrgb2, GPUrgb1, d_right_disp);


    Mat filtered_disp_vis;
    d_left_disp.download(left_disp);
    d_right_disp.download(right_disp);



    double lambda = 5000;
    double sigma = 1.5;
    wls_filter->setLambda(lambda);
    wls_filter->setSigmaColor(sigma);
    wls_filter->filter(left_disp, rgb1, filtered_disp, right_disp);

    imshow("filtered disparity", filtered_disp);
```

One more question, for the distance calculation using reprojectImageTo3D, should I divide 16 as my disparity map is in CV_8U?

Thanks in advance if anyone could help!